# Statement.execute() returning false even though changes are made

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

For this piece of my code here:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM assignments WHERE assign_mark = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setInt(1, d1);

boolean rows = statement.execute();
if (rows == true) {
    new ViewDatabase(user, name, pswrd);
    System.out.println("ASSIGN - ASSIGN_MARK UPDATE SUCCESSFUL!");
    frame.setVisible(false);
} else if (rows == false) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot find row!",
              "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

statement.close();
connection.close();
```

After I enter the value of d1 (which corresponds to the correct column of an existing data in my database), I get the "Cannot find row!" value. However, when I check my database, said row with d1 in column name is gone. I'm not sure what error/misunderstanding of concept I have here.

Comment: You ran the code *after* already deleting? Also you need to check what the driver returns for a DELETE. The return value might not mean what you think it means

Comment: You might be better with: `int numColsAffected = statement.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @g00se no I ran the code BEFORE it was deleted, but afterwards when I check my database the row isn't there anymore. For some weird reason, your second suggestion does work! I have no idea what happened haha but thank you!!

Comment: OK have put it up as an answer for you to accept

Comment: If you see behaviour you think makes no sense, then read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()). The boolean returned by `execute()` does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numColsAffected = statement.executeUpdate();
if (numColsAffected > 0) {
   // Success
}
else {
   // Failure
}
```

is probably the way to go

Answer (score 3):

The `execute()` call returns `true` if the result would otherwise have returned a `ResultSet` object; it returns `false` otherwise, i.e. if it wanted to return nothing, or an update count.

For just about all intents and purposes, this means that `execute()` returns `true` for `SELECT` statements and `false` for everything else, including `DELETE`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` statements.

Most of all, it means: Don't ever call that method, it's utterly useless.

`executeUpdate` or `executeQuery` is what you want.

--

EDIT: As Mark pointed out in a very useful comment, this answer undeservedly denigrates `execute()`. Let's just say that the returned boolean is a bit bizarre, but then that's not the only bit of the JDBC API that's a bit unintuitive. The method has its uses; it's just the right method for this specific question. Do read the comment for more details :)

Comment: `execute()` is not "utterly useless", it is very useful for 1) executing unknown types of statement, allowing you to dynamically handle the result type, 2) executing statements with multiple result sets (e.g. multiple result sets, or a succession of result sets and update counts). In addition, on some database systems, using `execute()` instead of `executeUpdate` may provide a performance benefit (e.g. when requesting update counts requires an additional network roundtrip)